# How to navigate a folder to read images?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to sample some region of interests in my picture. So basically every 30 pixel ill take an ROI of 30x30 and then try to get a lot of sample pictures. I have tried to search for the same question and I got answers using VideoCapture and they did not work. I just want to know how to navigate a directory and select each image there apply my method to sample the image. However my novice C++ skills have reached their limits there. My code is the following:

this is the method I want to apply to each image I have in a directory located at per se "C:\Projects\DataSet"

```
  ********fileName definition (part of ROI class)***********************



  string ROI::fileName(size_t frameNumber)
   {
   const string filePrefix("C:\\Projects\\dataset-checkerboard\\Checkerboard\\");
   const string fileSuffix(".png");
   const size_t fileNumDigits(10);
   stringstream ss;
   ss << filePrefix;
   ss << setw(fileNumDigits) << setfill('0') << frameNumber;
   ss << fileSuffix;
   return ss.str();

   ************sampleROI definition***************

Mat ROI::sampleROI(cv::Mat img,  int width, int length){
cv::Mat sampled;
int limitx = img.cols - length;
int limity = img.rows - width;



for(int x = 0; x < limitx ; x += length){
    for(int y = 0; y < limity  ; y += width){


    sampled = img(Rect(cv::Point(x,y),cv::Size(width,length)));
         stringstream file;
         file << "C:\\Projects\\dataset-checkerboard\\Samples\\img" << i << " atPixel " << Point(x,y) << ".png";
         cv::imwrite(file.str(), sampled);

    }


    }



    return sampled;
   }


   *****************************Main*******************************
   ROI sampling ;

         int main( int argc, char** argv )
            {
                int m = 0;
                size_t t = 166;
                for(size_t i = 4; i < t; ++i) { //0000000004.png is my first image
                Mat i_t = imread(sampling.fileName(i), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
                sampling.sampleROI(i_t,30,30, i); //samples 30x30 image
                cout << "finished processing image: " << sampling.fileName(i) << endl;
       }
    return 0;
    }
```

For a single picture picture it works beautifully, the code above works its just to give you an idea what I want to do with the pics in the images.

I would like to have a kind of method that will help me navigate each image there, they are all named in sequence of 0000000###.png and the image count is 166. Using VideoCapture is not working.

EDIT: the for loop in the main method does not appear to repeat itself.

Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to click the check mark below the up down arrows if you like the answer

Comment: Can you post your complete code? What is sampling in main.cpp?

Comment: oh it is just a constructor for the class ROI. I just solved the problem, it was just that the program I wrote was taking the samples of the first image. Then went to the second image and overwrote all the samples from the first file. I added another argument to the 'sampleROI' ('sampleROI(Mat img, int width, int lengh, int i)'and let it iterate with the for loop. Worked like a charm, but @A.E.Drew you helped me reach this point. I also added the iteration to the file name, so it stopped overwriting the same file over and over again. Ill post the updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved a similar problem for a project like so:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using std::string;
using std::stringstream;
using std::setfill;
using std::setw;

using cv::imread;
using cv::Mat;

string fileName(size_t frameNumber)
{
  const string filePrefix("office/input/in");
  const string fileSuffix(".jpg");
  const size_t fileNumDigits(6);
  stringstream ss;
  ss << filePrefix;
  ss << setw(fileNumDigits) << setfill('0') << frameNumber;
  ss << fileSuffix;
  return ss.str();
}
...
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  // initial work, set t to last image number + 1
  // i could start at 0 if your first image is 0
  for(size_t i = 1; i < t; ++i) {
    Mat i_t = imread(fileName(i), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    // Do work
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I tried to implement your code, but the program exits with 0. so basically it skips the for loop. My guess is it doesn't recognize the file names there. like my first image with 0000000004.png , i set my i as 4. However it still exits :/

Comment: Just needed to edit the fileNumDigits so it would fit my image names. Worked like a charm! waiting for my 500,000 image samples to be written as we speak. Thank you

Comment: Actually I found out that it is not working. it only works for 1 image and then it stops. My concern is it is either overwriting my images or something. see code above

Comment: You can print the file names to std out for each iteration to verify that you are getting what you want. You can also check that your Mat.data is non-null after your imread to make sure you are getting data. If those two things show that you are finding and opening the right files, your problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

So I do not fully understand the question but here is my crack at it.
The basic idea is just `forlooping` through all the images and doing what you want with them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>


std::string path = "path/to/image/folder/";
std::stringstream ss;
std::string num = "";
for(int i = 0; i < 166; i++){
    ss << i;
    num = ss.str();

    if(num.length() == 1) num = "00" + num;
    if(num.length() == 2) num = '0' + num;

    cv::Mat img = cv::imread((path+num+".png").c_str(), 1);
    cv::Mat result = sampleROI(img,  1024, 1024);
    // do something

    ss.str("");
    ss.clear();
}
```